# Leaking code for pdf viewer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, pdf

I have written some code to display a page of a pdf file. Unfortunately, the code below appears to be leaking but i can't find the leak. Who can help me to improve this code? Thanks in advance.

```
    CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, pageNr);
    CGPDFPageRetain(page);

    CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox);

    float pdfScale = self.view.frame.size.width/pageRect.size.width;
    pageRect.size = CGSizeMake(pageRect.size.width*pdfScale, pageRect.size.height*pdfScale);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();   
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context,pageRect);
    CGAffineTransform pdfTransform = CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(page,kCGPDFMediaBox,self.view.bounds, 0, true);
    CGContextSaveGState (context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, self.view.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextConcatCTM (context, pdfTransform);
    CGContextClipToRect (context, CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page,kCGPDFMediaBox));
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context,page);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    UIImage *backgroundImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    CGPDFPageRelease(page);
```

Comment: You know you can just use `UIWebView` to display PDFs, right?

Comment: why do you use  CGPDFPageRetain(page); ... when then you use CGPDFPageRelease(page); ? Are all the lines of the code posted here in the same method? If so you don't need to retain/release it... then.. are you sure the leak is not in allocation of "pdf" and "pageNr"? you omitted the code for their allocation...

Answer (score 0):

If you are leaking the same is my application in CGContextDrawPDFPage, then it is a known issue, which is said to be corrected in iOs4.0, but it is actually not. Check this [Radar](http://www.openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=126402).

**UPDATE:** I have checked now and actually it is leaking now only on my iPhone 3 with iOs 4.1 on it, instead on iPhone4 (iOs 4.2) and iPad (iOs 4.2) is not leaking.